# How can I use SQL to find a record that is not in a table based on info from two other tables?

Tags: sql

I have very little SQL experience so please bear with me as I try to explain my problem.

I have three tables:

1. webforms
2. users
3. signing_rules

The records in these tables are all connected via a field that they share (GENID).

I want to check for instances where a record in the third table is not present when it ought to be. This is only the case for records which have very specific values in webforms and users both.

Therefore, I want to search for all records that fit the specific criteria from the first two tables and only return the ones whose GENIDs do NOT appear in the third table.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Some sample data would really be helpful here.  And also, please tell us which database you are using (e.g MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres).  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is an left join, however , I can help you better if you post up some sample data, some sample ddl and expected results. otherwise we are simply shooting darts in the dark.

Comment: Often in a case like this I use a left join with a where condition to check if the id in the 3rd table is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can usually be done with an anti-join, `EXISTS`, or `EXCEPT`. Today we'll use the anti-join

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    webforms w
        inner join
    Users u
        on
           w.GENID = u.GENID
        left join
    signing_rules sr
        on
           w.GENID = sr.GENID
where
  sr.GENID is null and
  /* Other conditions on webforms and users */
```

The combination of a `left join` and a where clause check for a column from that table that shouldn't be nullable means that the only results that end up in the result set are those rows where the `left join` failed - hence anti-join.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked immediately. I'll accept this answer in 5 minutes when it lets me. I really appreciate your answer. I was kinda close, but hadn't thought of left join cos I'm so inexperienced :)